# How Can I Programmatically Set Screen Rotation Configuration in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, screen-orientation

In Systems Preferences -> Displays on OS X it is possible to set the rotation of a connected screen.

Is there anyway I can set this value programmatically?

I can get the current setting using CGDisplayRotation.
I seem to be able to set many of the screen properties such as resolution in a simple transaction:

```
CGDisplayConfigRef config;
CGError error = CGBeginDisplayConfiguration(&config);
...
error = CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration(config, kCGConfigurePermanently);
```

...but I cannot find anyway to set this specific property.

Has anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by undocumented way.
Example sets display orientation on 90 degrease:

```
CGDirectDisplayID display = CGMainDisplayID();
io_service_t service = CGDisplayIOServicePort(display);
IOOptionBits options = (0x00000400 | (kIOScaleRotate90)  << 16);
IOServiceRequestProbe(service, options);
```

Constants are defined in IOKit.framework IOGraphicsTypes.h

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work for me ...and IOSServiceRequestProbe is deprecated in Mavericks with no replacement.